# Gridview with C# adding rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add a row to my gridview. i succeeded in adding text boxes, but i cannot extract the value 
It keeps telling me that object reference not set to an instance of an object. At this line it halts

```
string acc = Convert.ToString(((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("accountID")).Text);
```

Please what  am i doing wrong

Comment: You don't need to convert a string to a string(`TextBox.Text` returns already a string). How and where have you added the `TextBox` to the footer-row?

Comment: i added the textBox to the footer row in the method below     protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to convert a string to a string([`TextBox.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns already a string).

How and where have you added the `TextBox` to the footer-row?

> i added the TextBox to the footer row in `GridView1_RowDataBound`

`RowDataBound` isn't the right method for dynamic controls since it is called only on databinding and not on every postback. But dynamical controls need to be recreated on every postback.

So use [`RowCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated.aspx) instead to create controls dynamically and use `RowDataBound` to databind them.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "accountID";
        e.Row.Cells[indexOfColumn].Controls.Add(tb);
    }
}
```

Comment: so how do i use rowcreated. First to bind the textboxes that allows the user to enter the new data, secondly to capture data entered by the user into a database

Comment: @mayowaogundele: Edited my answer to privide an example. Note that `indexOfColumn` is the index of the column where you want to add the TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first check wether its a footer row ,then find the textBox in it

```
protected void grdAccounts_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
  {
   //get text box value here
  }
}
```

**In Button Click**

try this

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.FooterRow; 
firstName = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
```

Comment: but i think i am supposed to retrieve the content of the text on button click. So put the above code in _RowCommand and i was having errors

Comment: it still gives NullReferenceException after the textbox has been filled